# Unable to connect to Dynamics CE v.9.0 on-Premises

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have a problem with connecting my .net 4.6.2 console app to our on-Premises Dynamics CE v.9.0 installation.

I have the following code to connect:

```
CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

OrganizationServiceProxy = conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;
```

This is my connectionString

```
<add name="CRM" connectionString="Url=http://ServerFQDN/OrgUniqueName; Domain=Mydomain; Username=MyUser; Password=MyPW; AuthType=AD;"/>
```

I followed the instructions on the following page to generate the ConnectionString
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect

Unfortunately is the OrganizationServiceProxy null all the time.
When i look in my CRMServiceClient i do get the following in LastCrmError

> LastCrmError = "Unable to Login to Dynamics CRMOrganizationWebProxyClient is nullOrganizationWebProxyClient is null"

I updated all my NuGet packages to the newest Version:

- Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies is 9.0.2.5
- Microsoft.CrmSdk.Deployment is 9.0.2.5
- Microsoft.CrmSdk.Extensions is 7.1.0.1
- Microsoft.CrmSdk.Workflow is 9.0.2.5
- Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly is 9.0.2.7

Had anyone had the same Problem?
Do you have a tip for me what could be the Problem?

**EDIT**

I just noticed, that i am not able to Login via the .NET application but also PluginRegistration and XRMToolBox is not working.
I do assume there is an error with the authentication. Maybe in AD.

When i try to connect i now always get the two following errors:

> Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient
>   Source  : mscorlib
>   Method  : HandleReturnMessage
>   Error   : The caller was not authenticated by the service.

And

> Inner Exception Level 1: 
>   Source  : System.ServiceModel
>   Method  : ThrowIfNegotiationFault
>   Error   : The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.

**EDIT2**

If i login to the Deployment Manager i can see "Failed" in the Status field. I think this is related to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue.
The Problem was, that there was some mismatch in between our DB an the Deployment Manager.
The following Steps fixed our Problem:

- Delete the Organization in Deployment Manager
- Import the Organization again from an existing Organization in Deployment Manager
- Configure HTTPS (i think this was not necessary to fix the problem)

Hope this helps others.

PS: Here is a link that describes how you can configure HTTPS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/on-premises/post-installation-configuration-guidelines-dynamics-365

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line before creating *CrmServiceClient* object

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working either. I will am now a step ahead. I will update the Question.